# PHP/GD: Wind direction generated image from database value

Tags: php, ajax, pdo, gd

I am doing a weather system and i want to represent the windDirDegrees from my database as a compass and a pointer through GD Library generated image.

I am using PDO with sqlite2 database. Currently I have this code here but I don't think it will be useful.

[Code](http://playground.jwscripts.com/imagerotate.phps)

Any help?

Lets say I have an image of an arrow pointing up and I want to make it point to the given degree value from the database?

Comment: In your current code 'degrees' of rotation taken from GET request. You only need to change it to be read from database. What's the issue? windDirDegrees  value in other format or smth else?

Comment: @SKorolev The value is INTEGER and is just a simple number with  the range of between 0 and 360. I want to use that value in the code to define the direction of which the pointer should be pointing. So lets say if I have an image of an arrow I want it to point at the current degree.

Comment: I think using SVG would be the better choice for something like this …

Comment: @CBroe Yeah but my requirement is to do it with the GD library.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with the images you have.